# How to get details of group selection in streamlit-aggrid

Tags: python, ag-grid, streamlit

I am using [streamlit](https://streamlit.io/) extension [streamlit-aggrid](https://github.com/PablocFonseca/streamlit-aggrid) and I have a selectable table with row groups. I am not able to gather all details of the rows selected when selecting a grouped row.

Here is a runnable `issue_example.py`:

```py
import streamlit as st
from st_aggrid import AgGrid, ColumnsAutoSizeMode
import pandas as pd

#_ Input data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Category': ['Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Vegetable', 'Vegetable'],
    'Items': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Tomato', 'Carrots'],
    'Price': [1.04, 1.15, 1.74, 1.5]})

#_ Ag Grid table
st.markdown('# Issue: how to get group selection?')
st.write("Try selecting an aggregate, and then an atomic record")

grid_options = {
    "columnDefs":   [
                        {"field": "Category", "rowGroup": True, "hide": True},
                        {"field": "Items"},
                        {"field": "Price"},
                    ],
    "rowSelection": "single",
    }

#_ Playing with response
response = AgGrid(
    df,
    grid_options,
    columns_auto_size_mode=ColumnsAutoSizeMode.FIT_ALL_COLUMNS_TO_VIEW,
)

if response['selected_rows']:

    selection=response['selected_rows'][0]

    st.write("Current selection is provided as a nested dictionary, requesting `['selected_rows'][0]` value of AgGrid response:")
    st.write(selection)

    if "Items" in selection:
        st.markdown('#### Good!')
        Category = selection['Category']
        Item = selection['Items']
        Price = selection['Price']
        st.write(f"We know everything about current selection: you picked a `{Category}` called `{Item}`, with price `{Price}`!")
    else:
        st.markdown('#### Bad!')
        nodeId = response['selected_rows'][0]['_selectedRowNodeInfo']['nodeId']
        st.write(f"All we know is that a node with Id `{nodeId}` is selected.\n\r How do we know if you're looking for a `Fruit` or a `Vegetable`?")
```

when running the above with `streamlit run issue_example.py` and selecting the `Fruit` group row, the response of AgGrid is a dictionary that contains no information about the row details in `Fruit` group. It does not even tell me that I selected `Fruit`. I need to have a way to know that when I am selecting Fruit and that the selected rows inside are `Apple` and `Banana`.

See screenshot for the running streamlit app:

[image: streamlit app showing the described issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a hack on how to get the category selected. There is a hint on `"nodeId":"row-group-0"`.

If you select fruit, you will get row-group-0 and if you select vegetable you will get row-group-1.

Now take the unique values on the Category column. You will get a numpy array which supports an index to get the value.

To get which category just use the index that is derived from nodeId.

Use your code and modify after the else.

```
else:
    st.markdown('#### Bad!')
    nodeId = response['selected_rows'][0]['_selectedRowNodeInfo']['nodeId']
    st.write(f"All we know is that a node with Id `{nodeId}` is selected.\n\r How do we know if you're looking for a `Fruit` or a `Vegetable`?")

    # Get the unique category.
    unicat = df['Category'].unique()

    # Get the node id and convert to int.
    nid = response['selected_rows'][0]['_selectedRowNodeInfo']['nodeId']
    nid = int(nid[-1])  # take the last char and convert to int as index to unicat

    # Show selected description based on unicat.    
    selected = unicat[nid]
    st.write(f'selected: {selected}')
```

If you need to get the items, based on the selected category, just use the df.

```
sel_items = df.loc[df['Category'] == selected]
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: thanks, the hack is something I though about too. It gets more tricky when you have multiple group levels. In that case there is a single index and you need to order the group levels in the order in which they appear (and not sure what happens if the grid is sorted...). I will update the example to show an example with multiple group levels. Anyway this at the moment is defintely the best answer. I would wait a bit more if there is a better answer (possibly one without the hack) otherwise I will award you the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to add the following (based on [this section](https://streamlit-aggrid.readthedocs.io/en/docs/GridOptionsBuilder.html#st_aggrid.grid_options_builder.GridOptionsBuilder.configure_selection) of the docs) to enable selecting multiple rows / selecting the children of the group:

```
options.configure_selection(selection_mode="multiple", rowMultiSelectWithClick=True, groupSelectsChildren=True, groupSelectsFiltered=True)
```

Edit: here's a way you can do this with checkboxes, although I understand that might not be exactly what you're looking for

```
from st_aggrid import AgGrid, GridOptionsBuilder, GridUpdateMode, DataReturnMode
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Category': ['Fruit', 'Fruit', 'Vegetable', 'Vegetable'],
    'Items': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Tomato', 'Carrots'],
    'Price': [1.04, 1.15, 1.74, 1.5]})

gb = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(df)
gb.configure_default_column(enablePivot=True, enableValue=True, enableRowGroup=True)
gb.configure_selection(selection_mode="multiple", use_checkbox=True)
gb.configure_side_bar()
gridoptions = gb.build()

response = AgGrid(
    df,
    gridOptions=gridoptions,
    enable_enterprise_modules=True,
    update_mode=GridUpdateMode.MODEL_CHANGED,
    data_return_mode=DataReturnMode.FILTERED_AND_SORTED,
    fit_columns_on_grid_load=False,
    header_checkbox_selection_filtered_only=True,
    use_checkbox=True)
```

Comment: I tested the above (which is essentially a different api for producing grid options with some changes to the keyword arguments) but it does not work, in the sense that it does not report the selected rows when selecting Fruit. Have you tested it yourself (the example is reproducible)? Note that the dataframe is already a pandas dataframe, no need for further conversion.

Comment: Hey sorry just noticed it was a Dataframe before! updated my answer.

Comment: I think I have a more complete working example somewhere, let me dig around for it

Comment: So according to aggrid, "groupSelectsChildren=True" is definitely the way to do this. Obviously you're right that it's not working correctly in this case, and I'm not sure if it's a bug with aggrid, or a result of the fact that we're using the streamlit-aggrid component. I'm asking around internally to see if anyone has been able to get this to work. Here's the aggrid page I was looking at: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/row-selection/#group-selection

Comment: yes, that section is relevant and indeed I would like to understand if it is possible to access to `api.getSelectedNodes()` from streamlit aggrid. I imagine it would contain what I need. Thanks for the help

Comment: and the answer with checkboxes is useful, but yeah, not exactly what I am looking for :)

Comment: I haven't really been able to find an Aggrid example that actually shows a "group" row that can be selected without a checkbox. I'll keep looking but I'm wondering if "groupSelectsChildren=True" is basically just referring to selection via checkbox? I'm not sure